# How to define a common interpolator for all transitions of a MotionScene?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-motionlayout

I have three states in a given layout, and I'd like to have the same interpolator used for any transition between these states. How can I define (either in XML or code) the same interpolator for all transitions without having to repeat myself as below?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state_a"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/state_b"
        motion:motionInterpolator="easeOut"
        motion:duration="250"/>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state_a"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/state_c"
        motion:motionInterpolator="easeOut"
        motion:duration="250"/>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state_b"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/state_c"
        motion:motionInterpolator="easeOut"
        motion:duration="250"/>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_a">...</ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_b">...</ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_c">...</ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to define an interpolator or duration common to all three Transitions:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:motionInterpolator="easeOut"
        motion:duration="250" />

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state_a"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/state_b" />

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state_a"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/state_c" />

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/state_b"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/state_c" />

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_a">...</ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_b">...</ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_c">...</ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Looking at the current MotionLayout source (v2.0.1), `Transition` elements that don't specify neither `constraintSetStart` nor `constraintSetEnd` are considered *abstract*, and its attributes become default to all Transitions in the MotionScene.

```java
public static class Transition {
    private boolean mIsAbstract = false;
    private int mConstraintSetEnd = -1;
    private int mConstraintSetStart = -1;
    // ...

    // This constructor creates a Transition based on another Transition
    Transition(MotionScene motionScene, MotionScene.Transition global) {
        if (global != null) {
            this.mDefaultInterpolator = global.mDefaultInterpolator;
            this.mDuration = global.mDuration;
            // ...
        }
    }

    private void fill(MotionScene motionScene, Context context, TypedArray a) {
        // Parse attributes from TypedArray, constraintSetStart being one of them
        if (this.mConstraintSetStart == -1) {
            this.mIsAbstract = true;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

When a Transition in the MotionScene is fully abstract (no start or end specified), it becomes the `mDefaultTransition`:

```java
public class MotionScene {
    private MotionScene.Transition mDefaultTransition = null;
    private ArrayList<MotionScene.Transition> mAbstractTransitionList = new ArrayList();
    // ...
}
```

It works as I described, but there isn't any reference to this in the current documentation. <s>Unfortunately, I can't link to the source, because the latest versions are not available in AOSP (see this issue). The only way of seeing this code is through IntelliJ's decompiler.</s> **EDIT: Links from [@hoford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63727805/7546633)**

This possibility was first mentioned in the [release notes of beta4](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout#2.0.0-beta4). Source available at https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the "Abstract" Transition. Was mentioned in the release notes of beta4
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout#2.0.0-beta4

Note, it does not become the base for other

You can find the source code at https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout

Unfortunately there no good way of documenting a feature of not putting something in.

Comment: Thank you for those links! Hope you don't mind me updating my answer with those.